# How to add group to a user without removing other group in suse linux with usermod?

Tags: group, accounts

I have one user, which has one primary group & one secondary group, like:

```
[ testuser Welcome ~ ]$ id

uid=2000(testuser) gid=2000(testuser) groups=2000(testuser),27(sudo),2001(testgroup)
```

Primary group is `testuser` & secondary group is `testgroup`.

Now, I try to add one more secondary group  testgroup2 to that user with below command

```
usermod -G testgroup2 testuser
```

but it removed the previous secondary group (`testgroup`) & added the new one. My need is that previous secondary group should not be removed & the new secondary group should be added.

I saw in ubuntu, there is one option like `-a` which can append the group to user without removing the other group.

Please let me know is it also possible on suse linux or not...?

Thankx !!!

Comment: He is also in secondary group `sudo`.

Comment: The version of usermod in opensuse 13.1 has the `-a` option. What version do you have?

Comment: What version of suse or opensuse are you running?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3

Answer (score 4):

In SLES11 SP3, the `usermod` command (from pwdutils 3.2.15) supports a `-A` option that will do what you want:

```
-A, --add-to-group group,...
    With this option a list of  groups can be specified, which the user should
    become a member of. Each group is separated from the next one only by a comma,
    without whitespace.
```

In SLES12 and OpenSUSE 13.1, the `usermod` command (from the more widely-used shadow-utils 4.1.5.1) supports a `-a` option to be used in conjunction with the `-G` option:

```
-a, --append
    Add the user to the supplemental group(s). Use only with -G option.

-G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
    A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each group
    is separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace. 

    If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user
    will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be changed via the -a option,
    which appends the user to the current supplementary group list.
```

Comment: The second option, `usermod -G groupName -a userName` is the right one in Arch currently

Answer (score 4):

If your `usermod` has no way to append (not even `-A`), try tacking on the current set of groups:

```
usermod -G "$(groups testuser | sed 's/.*: //;s/ /,/g'),testgroup2" testuser
```

Comment: CentOS 6.6 does nothing with `usermod -a -G squid testuser` . It states the `-a, --append` option in the man page but when I ran the command I stated it returned the response `no changes` which is what it had done. However your command worked, before I tried putting the -a after the group name and before the username.

Answer (score 1):

This command makes you specify a list of all groups, it replaces the old ones.

```
 -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
           A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same restrictions as the group given with the -g option.
```

Instead use `adduser`:

```
adduser [options] user group
```

`adduser` can be used to add a user, but also to add a user to a group.

---

or as @mark plotnick points out, use the `-a` option of `usermod`

Comment: thank you for your reply..but -a option is not available in suse linux, is there any other option to append the group without removing the old group.